# Does Mapbox offline region completedTileCount take into account of overlapping regions?

Tags: java, android, maps, mapbox, mapbox-gl

So I am implementing an app which downloads Mapbox tiles for given offline region.Since Mapbox has a lint of 6000 tiles. I want to notify the user how much tiles he has downloaded. I am using the `completedTileCount` in the `OfflineRegionStatus`. Now the question is does this take into account of overlapping region tiles as Mapbox says they don't re download overlapping tiles.